# I need to change slider value and send it when it its get submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change and store the value of the slider mean some value coming from the backend and I am storing it in the state showing in the slider but what I need to set if I change slider value like example first value is **partialNameMatchThreshold: 40**, and I change it **partialNameMatchThreshold: 50** then when I submit it whatever I change that vale need to submit mean **partialNameMatchThreshold: 50**, need to submit but what happening my scenario that value not updating you can see updateSlider function I created and also check code sandbox link I am adding blow.

```
partialNameMatchThreshold: 40,
dOBMatchThreshold: 100
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formText: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(-2)
  }
}));
const marks = [
  {
    value: 0
  },
  {
    value: 20
  },
  {
    value: 40
  },
  {
    value: 60
  },
  {
    value: 80
  },
  {
    value: 100
  }
];
function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}
function valueLabelFormat(value) {
  return marks.findIndex((mark) => mark.value === value) + 2;
}

function valueLabelFormatDob(value) {
  return marks.findIndex((marks) => marks.value === value) + 1;
}
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  listType: Yup.array()
    .of(Yup.string())
    .min(1, "Required!")
    .required("Required!"),
  Start_Date: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
  End_Date: Yup.string().required("Required!")
});

const fetchSearchRule = {
  user: 0,
  partialNameMatch: true,
  partialNameMatchThreshold: 40,
  DOBMatch: true,
  dOBMatchThreshold: 100
};

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [changeRuleSettings, setChangeRuleSettings] = React.useState(false);
  const [rules, setRules] = React.useState(fetchSearchRule);

  // React.useEffect(() => {

  // }, []);
  const ruleForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      SetupForm: rules,
      ManagerSetupFormIntialValue: {},
      changeRuleSettings: false,
      FormChangeCount: 0
    },
    // validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values.SetupForm, null, 2));
      // initiateRules(values);
    }
  });
  const [value, setValue] = useState(ruleForm.initialValues);

  const handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
    setRules({
      ...rules,
      [e.target.name]: !rules[e.target.name]
    });
    value.FormChangeCount = 1;
  };
  const updateSlider = (e,newDays) => {
    if (e.target.name === "partialDOBMatchThreshold") {
      setRules({
        ...rules,
        name:e.target.name, value: newDays,
      });
      value.FormChangeCount = 1;
    } else {
      setRules({
        ...rules,
        name:e.target.name, value: newDays,
      });
      value.FormChangeCount = 1;
    }
  };

  const style = changeRuleSettings
    ? { cursor: "pointer" }
    : { cursor: "not-allowed" };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ruleForm.handleSubmit}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box className={classes.formText}>
            <Checkbox
              style={style}
              name="partialNameMatch"
              checked={rules.partialNameMatch}
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
              onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              Partial Match
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          {rules.partialNameMatch && (
            <Slider
              isChangeAllowed={changeRuleSettings}
              onChange={updateSlider}
              name="partialNameMatchThreshold"
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              aria-label="pretto slider"
              defaultValue={rules.partialNameMatchThreshold}
              // updateSliderChange={updateSlider}
              getAriaValueText={valuetext}
              step={10}
              marks={marks}
              name="partialNameMatchThreshold"
            />
          )}
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
            <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold">D.O.B Rule</Box>
          </Typography>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box className={classes.formText}>
            <Checkbox
              style={style}
              name="DOBMatch"
              checked={rules.DOBMatch}
              onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
              color="primary"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              Date Match
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          {rules.DOBMatch && (
            <Slider
            // isChangeAllowed={changeRuleSettings}
            
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            aria-label="pretto slider"
            valueLabelFormat={valueLabelFormat}
            defaultValue={rules.partialDOBMatchThreshold}
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            onChange={updateSlider}
            // updateSliderChange={updateSlider}
            step={20}
            marks={marks}
            name="partialDOBMatchThreshold"
          />
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid xs={12} item>
        <Divider></Divider>
        <Box
          mt={2}
          display="flex"
          alignItems="flex-end"
          flexDirection="column"
          mt={2}
        >
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
            Changes
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[codeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mccarthy-5461b?file=/src/App.js:1100-1173)

Comment: I don't know Formik, but it seems it acts like a middleware between your form elements and the interface. Thus, it seems to me that your values are not being updated because you are using different handlers for your inputs logics. 
I'd say Formik is not compatible to keep track of Material elements' states.

As you are keeping record of your changes on App state, why don't you use your own submit logic handling  

Have you tried using Formik with normal inputs to check if it is correctly hooking into the form state?

Comment: yeah it's coming in the state but it's not  storing  value in partialDOBMatchThreshold mean if I change the slider then when I submit it its show one another  variable name value and storing value in the value variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using two different states to handle your form. Formik uses its own state and it's not aware of the App state. If you decide to stick with Formik, you should refactor your component to get your inputs values from your *SetupForm* object, and not from the App state.

On Formik docs, they teach how to hook it with Material-UI:
https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui

But basically, you should change your references to point them to your ruleForm, as here:

```
<Checkbox
  name="SetupForm.DOBMatch"
  style={style}
  checked={ruleForm.values.SetupForm.DOBMatch}
  onChange={ruleForm.handleChange}
  color="primary"
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
/>
```

Please note that if you want to conditionally exhibit the Slider according to the state of the Checkbox, you should also handle the checkboxes states on the App, as updating your ruleForm object won't cause a re-render on the application.

Comment: ok got it but when true comes from the backend it's not checked by default if I set like this checked={ruleForm.values.SetupForm.DOBMatch}

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it on your sandbox and yeah, it seems that there's something wrong as for some reason material-ui is not passing down the name attribute to the target of the event. I've found some users complaining about it... I dunno, if it really doesn't work as expected, maybe try to choose between Formik or Material-UI... :/